# Laravel: Multiple Route to Same Controller

Tags: laravel

May I know how can I make just a single route so I don't have to repeat it? Thanks in advance.

```
Route::get('/url', 'CtcFormController@index' )->name('CtcForm.ch');
Route::post('/url/submit', 'CtcFormController@submit')->name('CtcForm.submit');
Route::view('/url/submitted', 'form.submit')->name('CtcForm.submit');

Route::get('/url2','CtcFormController@store')->name('CtcForm.eng');
Route::post('/url2/submit', 'CtcFormController@submit')->name('CtcForm.submit');
Route::view('/url2/submitted', 'form.submit')->name('CtcForm.submit');
```

Comment: You can use [resource route](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#resource-controllers)

Comment: your `submit` and `submitted` url are same..going to the same controller method. you can merge them. but just `url` is different. you can't merge them.

Answer (score 1):

As per your given example, you want to handle the variable part of the route which is `/url/` and `/url12/`. Yes! you can handle there both different route using a single route in ways:
Use route variable to handle dynamic `url` values i.e. url, url2,url3...url12 and so on.

```
Route::get('/{url}', 'CtcFormController@index' )->name('CtcForm.ch');
Route::post('/{url}/submit', 'CtcFormController@submit')->name('CtcForm.submit');
Route::view('/{url}/submitted', 'form.submit')->name('CtcForm.submit');
```

Now in your controller methods handing above routes receive extra parameter $url like:
In controller CtcFormController.php class:

```
public function index(Request $request, string $url) {
       //$url will gives you value from which url request is submitted i.e. url or url12
      //method logic goes here ...
}
```

Similarly, method handling `/{url}/submit` route will be like:

```
public function submit(Request $request, string $url) {
    //method logic goes here ...
}
```

Let me know if you have any further query regarding this or you face any issue while implementing it.